# How do I convert the content of System.out.print to a String variable in java

Tags: java, string, javafx, output, system.out

I have this line of code:

```
    System.out.print(postalCodeIndex.findClosestBruteForce(latitude, longitude));
```

It returns output from a text file that was ran through an algorithm. For example the output is can be : "`A0E 2Z0 Monkstown Newfoundland NL D [47.150300:-55.299500]`". I would like to convert that output to a string so I can use it in a javafx GUI text. Is that posible?

Comment: I wish that you read the docs.

Comment: I have already tried the posted answer before. I get this error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from PostalCode to String` It wasn't a string to begin with, I'm just asking if a conversion is possible. This output is returned from a search algorithm that processed a file

Comment: Can someone be helpful instead of just down voting? like not just down vote and say why?

Comment: (1) I didn't vote down.  (2) Even if one does, one doesn't need to explain.  Your question asks something rather trivial that could be answered without much effort.  (3) Another reason to downvote the question would be that it doesn't really add value to the site.

Comment: I did not down vote, but I assume people did because this question could be answered in about 3 seconds by a google search/reading basic documentation

Comment: Ok. Should i delete this question?

Comment: No, don't delete the question, this is something that beginning Java developers often struggle with. Besides, there's no such thing as a stupid question - now you know a bit more!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

System.out.print accepts a String as a parameter, in fact, anything that you send it will be converted to a String in order for it to be displayed.

Using the following code, you could then put the result of the postalCodeIndex method call into a variable called myString.

```
String myString = postalCodeIndex.findClosestBruteForce(latitude, longitude).toString();
```

It might be worth your while remembering that the process in the System.out.print() code sample works as follows:

1. postalCodeIndex is called FIRST, creating a temporary String in-place because the .toString() method is called on your behalf.
2. The System.out.print method is only called AFTER the postalCodeIndex method has returned, because System.out.print requires this returned String to enable it to print something to the console.

Comment: Thanks. This has actually fixed my problem. The conversion is indeed posible

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It's helped me to understand how system.print.out works a little better

Comment: @TatakaiWasumi  Excellent! I'm glad I was able to help, and thank you for taking the time to send a comment. Best wishes with your Java adventure.

Answer (score 4):

```
postalCodeIndex.findClosestBruteForce(latitude, longitude)
```

this method it self would returning a String or if not you can do like

```
String str = postalCodeIndex.findClosestBruteForce(latitude, longitude).toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the code you've given, the code inside the System.out.print() call will return a PostalCode object. So to get a string you could do something like:

```
String x = postalCodeIndex.findClosestBruteForce(latitude, longitude).toString();
//use x as String
```

Comment: I have tried that. Type mismatch: cannot convert from PostalCode to String

Comment: Without any information about your PostalCode Class, it is impossible for me to know what type is returned from the findClosestBruteForce() method. Now knowing that it returns a PostalCode object, I suggest you call the toString() method of the object returned. If it does not look the way you want you can override the toString() method to make it look better. I suggest you include this important information in your future questions.

Comment: @TatakaiWasumi `postalCodeIndex.findClosestBruteForce(latitude, longitude).toString()`?